# hadoop mapreduce job getting stuck at map 0% reduce 0%

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Following the documentation for hadoop setup on a single node cluster, I installed hadoop and then when I tried to run one of the examples present, `hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar`, the process seems to get stuck at map 0% reduce 0% in `running` state. 
My system spec is 1TB physical memory, 8GB RAM, 4 cores.

`mapred-site.xml` is:

```
<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
 <value>2000</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
 <value>500</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
 <value>2500</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
 <value>3</value>
 <source>yarn-default.xml</source>
</property>
```

`yarn-site.xml`

```
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
 <value>1000</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
 <value>1000</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
 <value>-Xmx800m</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
 <value>-Xmx800m</value>
</property>
```

Console Log:

```
16/09/30 11:38:08 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/09/30 11:38:10 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 0
16/09/30 11:38:11 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:0
16/09/30 11:38:11 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1475215403708_0001
16/09/30 11:38:12 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1475215403708_0001
16/09/30 11:38:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://DeadSilence:8088/proxy/application_1475215403708_0001/
16/09/30 11:38:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1475215403708_0001 
16/09/30 11:38:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1475215403708_0001 running in uber mode : false
16/09/30 11:38:23 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
```

Comment: can you provide what example are you running and the complete log?

Comment: As specified in the question, `hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar` is the name of file that I am trying to run. As for the message after running the example, please see the updated question. Thanks in advance

Comment: there is no input to the job '16/09/30 11:38:10 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 0'. Are you planning on providing any input?

Comment: When I provide some actual input, the process gets struck even before it starts running i.e., in accepted state.`ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM` and total container allocated is `0`.

Comment: you need to update the resource-manager address. yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address to hostname

Comment: After explicitly providing yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address to be localhost:8031, job starts running but again gets stuck at map 0% reduce 0%

Comment: can you provide the new logs?